# Add a semi-opaque black layer over a background image in Android TextView

Tags: android, background, drawable, transparent

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a .png image as background for my TextView; The color of the text is white. To make the text easier to read, I'd like add a seme-opaque, black layer on top of my .png image.

This is what I've done so far:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/aboutContent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:text="@string/aboutEN"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:background="@drawable/myimage"/>
```

I tried to add android:background="@color/blackOpaque">
But Eclipse complains that I've already got a background image. So I tried to change the transparency of my image file like this:

```
Drawable myimage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
myimage.setAlpha(50);
```

But nothing seems to happen at all.

What should I do? Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This saved my @$$!](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@drawable/myimage" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/aboutContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/aboutEN"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```